# Detect Keypress and Delay Until Key Released AppleScript

Tags: applescript, keypress

I am having trouble figuring out how to detect a key being pressed in AppleScript and how to delay until that key is released.  I want to make a toggle for zoom, and I have everything else (I think).  This is my current code

```
on idle
    set ztoggle to 0

    repeat

        --how do i make it so a key is needed to run this loop? maybe an 'if (im not sure what to put here) then' loop?--
            if (ztoggle = 1) then
                set ztoggle to 0
            else if (ztoggle = 0) then
                set ztoggle to 1
            end if
        --how do i make it so the program waits at this line until the key from before is released? i was thinking delay, but im not sure--


        if (ztoggle = 1) then
            tell application "System Events"
                key code 28 using {option down, command down}
            end tell
        end if

        set ztoggle to 0

    end repeat
end idle
```

Does anyone know how I would do this?  Also, this is my first time trying anything with AppleScript, so if I messed up elsewhere, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with ("vanilla") AppleScript. The only thing close to it is to check for a modifier key being pressed by using the third-party command line binary "checkModifierKeys" (https://github.com/reggiezhang/checkModifierKeys)[edit: new url - thanks, @jerry-t].

You'd have to use something like

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/checkModifierKeys control"
```

in a repeat loop. It does work well.

Comment: The link is dead. I found this one on github (not sure the same author): https://github.com/reggiezhang/checkModifierKeys  Works great.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done without any 3rd-party additions, but instead calling into the cocoa framework:

```applescript
use framework "Cocoa"
use scripting additions

global ca
set ca to current application

to isModifierPressed(modifier)
    ((ca's NSEvent's modifierFlags()) / modifier as integer) mod 2 is equal to 1
end isModifierPressed

repeat until isModifierPressed(ca's NSEventModifierFlagControl)
    delay 0.1 -- sad poll/wait loop :(
end repeat
display dialog "Control was pressed"
```

Note that `NSEvent's modifierFlags()` is a bitfield and `NSEventModifierFlagControl` is a 2<sup>n</sup> bit flag, these need to be bitwise-ANDed together to see if the key is held.  AppleScript doesn't have bitwise operators (!!) so in this case the AND is emulated arithmetically - first by integer dividing the modifierFlags() bitfield by the NSEventModifierFlagControl bitflag, then seeing if the result is odd.

`modifierFlags()` only reports instantaneous modifier status, so we must poll it in a loop to wait for a keypress.

[Other modifier keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nseventmodifierflags) may also be checked this way.  They are:

| Syntax | Description |
| --- | --- |
| NSEventModifierFlagCapsLock | The Caps Lock key has been pressed. |
| NSEventModifierFlagShift | The Shift key has been pressed. |
| NSEventModifierFlagControl | The Control key has been pressed. |
| NSEventModifierFlagOption | The Option or Alt key has been pressed. |
| NSEventModifierFlagCommand | The Command key has been pressed. |
| NSEventModifierFlagNumericPad | A key in the numeric keypad or an arrow key has been pressed. |
| NSEventModifierFlagHelp | The Help key has been pressed. |
| NSEventModifierFlagFunction | A function key has been pressed. |
| NSEventModifierFlagDeviceIndependentFlagsMask | Device-independent modifier flags are masked. |